# Using part of the select clause without rewriting it

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using an Oracle SQL Db and I am trying to count the number of terms starting with X letter in a dictionnary.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT Substr(Lower(Dict.Term),0,1) AS Initialchar,
       Count(Lower(Dict.Term))
FROM Dict
GROUP BY Substr(Lower(Dict.Term),0,1)
ORDER BY Substr(Lower(Dict.Term),0,1);
```

This query is working as expected, but the thing that I'm not really happy about is the fact that I have to rewrite the long "Substr(Lower(Dict.Term),0,1)" in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause. Is there any way to reuse the one I defined in the SELECT part ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery.  Because Oracle follows the SQL standard, `substr()` starts counting at 1.  Although Oracle does explicitly allow 0 (["If position is 0, then it is treated as 1"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)), I find it misleading because "0" and "1" refer to the same position.

So:

```
select first_letter, count(*)
from (select d.*, substr(lower(d.term), 1, 1) as first_letter
      from dict d
     ) d
group by first_letter
order by first_letter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The output columns can only be referred to in the `ORDER BY` clause, but not used in any other way. The only way would be to make it into a subselect, but it wouldn't be any clearer and might cause issues with performance.

Comment: You can refer to the `initialChar` alias in the order by clause. But that's only half the issue, and you can't refer to it in the group by clause, so it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/state.htm#TTSQL503) for this purpose.

```
with init as (
 select  substr(lower(d.term), 1, 1) as Initialchar
 from dict d)
select Initialchar, count(*)
from init
group by Initialchar
order by Initialchar;
```

Contrary to opposite meaning, IMO this makes the query much clearer and defines natural order; especially while using more subqueries.

I'm not aware about performance caveats, but there are some limitation, such as it not possible to use `with` clause within another `with` clause: `ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause`.